# Open Modal from Expo tabs navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, bottom-sheet

I'm encountering an issue while working with Expo's Bottom Tabs Navigator and the @gorhom/bottom-sheet library. I have a total of 5 tabs, and my goal is to ensure that the middle tab consistently opens a modal overlay above any other screen. This overlay should have a transparent background, allowing me to see the content of the underlying screen. Unfortunately, I've been struggling to achieve this desired behavior.

app/_layout.tsx

```
function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();


  return (
    // <GestureHandlerRootView>

    <BottomSheetContextProvider>
      <BottomSheetModalProvider>
        <TamaguiProvider config={config}>
          <Theme name={"light_orange"}>
            <ToastProvider>
              <ToastViewport />

              <ThemeProvider
                value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
              >
                <Stack>
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="(tabs)"
                    options={{ headerShown: false }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="modal"
                    options={{ presentation: "modal" }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="modal-teste"
                    options={{ presentation: "modal" }}
                  />
                </Stack>
              </ThemeProvider>
            </ToastProvider>
          </Theme>
        </TamaguiProvider>
      </BottomSheetModalProvider>
    </BottomSheetContextProvider>
  );
}
```

/(tabs)/_layout.tsx

```
export default function TabLayout() {
  const [teste] = useState(null);
  const { setIsOpen } = useBottomSheetContext();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const { expand } = useBottomSheet();
  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? "light"].tint,
      }}
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="calendar-tab"
        options={{
          title: "Calendario",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Calendar color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="historic-tab"
        options={{
          title: "Historico",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <FileClock color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="monitoring-tab" <- this one
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <PlusCircle color={color} />,
        }}
      />

      <Tabs.Screen
        name="analysis-tab"
        options={{
          title: "Analises",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <AlarmPlus color={color} />,
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

And my monitoring-tab with the modal

```
const MonitoringPage = () => {
  // ref
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  // variables
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ["25%", "50%"], []);

  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
    console.log("handleSheetChanges", index);
  }, []);

  // renders
  return (
    // <View style={styles.container}>
    <BottomSheet
      ref={bottomSheetRef}
      index={1}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
      onChange={handleSheetChanges}
    >
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <Text>Awesome </Text>
      </View>
    </BottomSheet>
    // </View>
  );
};
```